# Using instance variables as named format substitutions

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program that generates a C++ program.  There are a whole bunch of instances of code like this:

```
class TestBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, mod, name, casetype, generator):
        self.mod = mod
        self.name = name
        self.casetype = casetype
        self.generator = generator

    def fullname(self):
        return "{mod}.{name}".format(**self.__dict__)

    def write_cases(self, outf):
        outf.write("const {casetype} {mod}_{name}[] = {{\n"
                   .format(**self.__dict__))
        for case in self.generator():
            outf.write("  { " + case + " },\n")
        outf.write("};\n\n")
```

The `"text {subst}".format(**self.__dict__)` construction is the only way I have found to make the instance variables of `self` available as named substitutions, and it's ugly and I do not like it.  I would like to be able to write `"text {subst}".format(self)`; is this possible, and if so, how?  I'm aware that `"text {0.subst}".format(self)` will work out of the box and `"text {subst}".format(**self)` can be made to work with a few special methods, but both of those still have extra gunk.

Comment: Aside: `vars(self)` looks cleaner to me than `self.__dict__`, and I think `.format(**vars(self))` reads pretty well.  `Format using-as-keyword-arguments the vars of self`.  But it's much longer than `{0.subst}` which I don't even like that much because I had to think for a minute about why it works..

Comment: You seem to be here for a long time. I think people can expect from you to already be able to seperate between your real life environment (e.g. your C++ generater or the `Testblock` class) and your problem, which seems to be about transfering a random object's attributes (no need for `self`) to a list of params (no need for `format` or strings).

Comment: @erikb85 I like to include enough context to make clear why I want to do the thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Zack you have a point there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the functionality in a function:

```
def fmt(msg, obj):
    return msg.format(**obj.__dict__)
```

Then:

```
def fullname(self):
    return fmt("{mod}.{name}", self)
```

Comment: I'm going to leave the question open a little longer in case someone has something really clever, but I like this idea (with `fmt` a method of the class in question).

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a general way to do what you want.  You could write your class so it has a `__getitem__` method that delegates item access to attribute access (that is, makes `obj['foo']` the same as `obj.foo`).  But then you can't use item access for anything else.  And you can't do this for third-party classes that don't define item access in this way.

You could alternatively create a utility function that creates a mapping object wrapping your object, so you'd do `"text {subst}".format(wrapper(self))`, but if `{0.subst}' is already "too much gunk" for you that probably won't satisfy you either.

The `format` method isn't a general-purpose thing for mapping names in any namespace into format strings.  It maps keys in a mapping, not attributes on an object.  If you want to map attributes on an object, you have to get them into a mapping somehow.  "{0.subst}" isn't really that bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound for some reason to use string.format (e.g., you're just using strings, don't need the format mini-language), something like this might be useful:

```
import re


SUB_RE = re.compile(r"{(.*?)}")

class Formattable(object):
   def format(self, s):
      def repl(matchobj):
         var = matchobj.group(1).strip()
         try:
            retval = getattr(self, var)
         except AttributeError:
            retval = "ERROR"
         return retval

      return SUB_RE.sub(repl, s)



class Test(Formattable):
   def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
      self.foo = foo
      self.bar = bar
      self.baz = baz

t = Test('myFoo', 'bbbbbar', 'BAZZZZ')
print t.format("foo = {foo}")
print t.format("bar = {bar} but baz is {baz}")
```

prints

```
foo = myFoo
bar = bbbbbar but baz is BAZZZZ
```

Comment: Nice idea/implementation. Need some escape mechanism for literal `{` and `}` characters though, because for example `t.format("foo = {foo} {}")` produces an erroneous result.

Comment: Yeah, definitely -- for production use I'd want to spend more than 5 minutes thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this using `string.Template`:

```
from string import Template

class TestBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, mod, name, casetype, generator):
        self.mod = mod
        self.name = name
        self.casetype = casetype
        self.generator = generator

    def subst(self, format):  # added method
        return Template(format).substitute(self.__dict__)

    def fullname(self):
        return self.subst("$mod.$name")

    def write_cases(self, outf):
        outf.write(self.subst("const $casetype ${mod}_$name[] = {{\n"))
        for case in self.generator():
            outf.write("  { " + case + " },\n")
        outf.write("};\n\n")

import sys

def generator():
    for v in ['normal', 'extraordinary']: yield v

tb = TestBlock('somemod', 'somename', 'somecasetype', generator)

sys.stdout.write('fullname: '+tb.fullname()+'\n')
tb.write_cases(sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
fullname: somemod.somename
const somecasetype somemod_somename[] = {{
  { normal },
  { extraordinary },
};
```

Note that substitutions can be triggered two different ways, either with `$name` or `${name}`. Both were used above.